# Angularjs-Slider onchange event not firing up?

Tags: angularjs, slider

I am using Range Slider from the [AngularJs Slider](https://github.com/rzajac/angularjs-slider) in my application. As per the documentation, I have used the on-change event which is not firing up.

Below is my code in HTML

```
<rzslider rz-slider-floor="editor.slider.min" rz-slider-ceil="editor.slider.max" rz-slider-model="editor.slider.selectedMin" rz-slider-high="editor.slider.selectedMax" rz-slider-step="1" rz-slider-on-change="onSliderChange()">
</rzslider>
```

Below is the controller code

```
editor.onSliderChange = function () {           
        console.log(editor.slider.selectedMin);
    }
```

Can someone help me on this regarding where I might have gone wrong?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You forget to add `editor.` prefix.

```
rz-slider-on-change="editor.onSliderChange()"
```